# SpringMVC RestEasy Integration Beans aren't injected to Controller classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, resteasy

I'm working on a project which has spring mvc 2.5.* .I have integrated RESTeasy to create restful endpoints. I have defined a controller class with @Controler. I have a bean which is supposed to be injected to this controller but it seems it's not getting injected, thus it throws a null pointer exception when the bean variable is used in controller rest methods.

I have added these to the web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/rest</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.test.package.controller.MyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Customized class I extended from resteasy Application class to define application path:

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
        // register root resource
        classes.add(EmployeeController.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

I have a servlet.xml which has defined mvc controller beans which works fine:
eg:

```
  <bean name="/testDetail.html" class="com.test.package.controller.TestDetailController" parent="baseController">
    <property name="testService" ref="testService"/>
  </bean>
```

My Controller class looks like this:

```
@Controller
@Path("/employee")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class EmployeeController {

private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(EmployeeController.class);

private EmployeeService employeeService; // This doesn't get initiated.

@PUT
@Path("/update/{empId}")
public Response updateEmp(@PathParam("empId") Long empId, EmpRequest request) {

    Response response = null;
    employeeService.update(request); // NULL POINTER THROWN HERE, employeeService is null

    return response;
}
public EmployeeService getEmployeeService () {
    return employeeService ;
}

public void serEmployeeService (EmployeeService employeeService ) {
    this.employeeService = employeeService ;
}
```

}

Here I added another bean to servlet.xml as,

```
  <bean id="employeeController " class="com.test.package.controller.EmployeeController">
    <property name="employeeService " ref="employeeService "/>
  </bean>
```

In a separate xml employeeService bean is defined. It' just that it won't reflect in the employeeController  bean. I'm not sure if even employeeController bean is created or not. But I'm able to call the endpoint successfully. bean initiation works fine if put employeeService bean in a MVC controller. eg:

```
  <bean name="/testDetail.html" class="com.test.package.controller.TestDetailController" parent="baseController">
    <property name="employeeService " ref="employeeService "/>
  </bean>
```

But not in RestController. Any Idea on this behavior. Am I missing any configuration here.

Answer (score 0):

firstly, you should define the `employeeService` bean as follows,

```
<bean id="employeeService" class="com.test.package.service.EmployeeService">
    --------
</bean>
```

load the above config xml file in web.xml,

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/XML_FILE_PATH/XML_FILE_NAME.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

then, you can use `employeeService` bean

use `@PostConstruct` annotation for invoke with this method after `employeeService` bean is initialized

```
@PUT
@PostConstruct
@Path("/update/{empId}")
public Response updateEmp(@PathParam("empId") Long empId, EmpRequest request) {

    Response response = null;
    employeeService.update(request); // NULL POINTER THROWN HERE, employeeService is null

    return response;
}
```

Comment: Like I said it's already defined in a sepearte xml. that xml is been imported too. Like i said it works fine when it's in a MVC controller bean
 <bean name="/testDetail.html" class="com.test.package.controller.TestDetailController" parent="baseController">
    <property name="employeeService " ref="employeeService "/>
  </bean>

Comment: sorry for the mistake, add this config xml file into web.xml

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience,.i think suggested two steps have completed in your project

Comment: please refer, above modified answer

Comment: It's already loaded in web.xml
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/emp-spring.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

inside the emp-spring.xml,
 <import resource="spring-service.xml" /> is imported. spring-service.xm has 
<bean id="employeeService" class="com.test.package.service.EmployeeService">
    --------
</bean>

Comment: use the `@PostConstruct` annotation for invoke with `updateEmp` method after `employeeService` bean is initialized. Please refer the answer